# using regex and casestatements statements in redshift

Tags: sql, regex, case, amazon-redshift

Hi I've been migrating queries from bigquery to redshift. I need to create a case statement using reg ex statements. Redshift doesn't seem to support the same regex_contains statement- how can I use regular expressions in redshift?

In bigquery I follow this syntax

```
    CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS (Campaign, '.*(?i)name.*') THEN 'brand' WHEN 
  REGEXP_CONTAINS (Campaign, '.*(?i)namee.*') THEN 'brand'
  ELSE 'Other'
 END AS BRAND 




 CASE  
WHEN campaign REGEXP_REPLACE  '.*(?i)name.*' THEN 'brand'
WHEN campaign REGEXP_REPLACE'.*(?i)campaign.*' THEN 'brand'
ELSE 'OTHER' 
End AS BRAND
```

I've been trying to follow redshifts regex but nothing seems to create the same output.

Answer (score 0):

You’re looking for the REGEXP_INSTR function. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_INSTR.html